# fetch only updated CNContacts from ContactStore swift2 xcode7

Tags: contacts, swift2, ios9, xcode7

I would like to getch all CNContact objects from Contacts Store that were updated externally so that I can refresh my list of contacts.

Xcode 7.0
ios9

Comment: do you have solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not Possible even with the Old framework.
what i'm doing (using ABAddressBook) is to start a background operation and for all saved contacts i test the modification date of the contact with the one i saved:

```
NSDate *lastModicationDate = (__bridge NSDate*)ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonModificationDateProperty);
```

but in the CNContact i can't see the modification date property, so i guess that we have to do this manually (check if there's a modification for every entries)

Answer (score 0):

As I read the head file `"ABPerson.h"`, Apple Inc. didn't give the hint of which api should use as `kABPersonModificationDateProperty` is deprecated as other apis.

Here is a part of the source head file.

```
AB_EXTERN const ABPropertyID kABPersonNoteProperty AB_DEPRECATED("use CNContact.note");// Note - kABStringPropertyType
AB_EXTERN const ABPropertyID kABPersonCreationDateProperty AB_DEPRECATED("");// Creation Date (when first saved)
AB_EXTERN const ABPropertyID kABPersonModificationDateProperty AB_DEPRECATED("");// Last saved date
```